# Firebase auth with only a single account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building an admin control panel for some personal stuff. The app itself is built with Vue.js and will be hosted using Firebase. I want to be able to sign in with Google thru Firebase. Since the app is only intended for me do I not want anyone else to be able to sign up. So can I make it so only my Google account will work to sign in with for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in three ways:

1. Firebase side
   Enable [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart) for reading and writing and they would never be able to pass your login screen, eg:

   {
       "rules": {
         "users": {
           "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === your-uid"
           }
         }
       }
     }
2. Whitelist your account under your Firebase console, and then when retrieving the email in your app, match to know if it is included in the whitelisted accounts
3. Publish it as Beta and just distribute it to the people you need (just you in your case)